# How do you draw a svg icon inside a circle element?

Tags: html, css, svg

```
<svg viewBox="-151 -323 4000 4000" style="" fill="blue">
  <g>
    <circle fill="blue" class="in-circle" r="110">
      <svg
        preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet"
        height="1em"
        width="1em"
        viewBox="0 0 40 40"
        style="vertical-align: middle;color: red;"
        fill="red"
      >
        <g>
          <path d="m33.5 29.5q0 0.9-0.7 1.5l-3 3.1q-0.6 0.6-1.5 0.6t-1.5-0.6l-6.6-6.6-6.5 6.6q-0.7 0.6-1.6 0.6t-1.5-0.6l-3-3.1q-0.6-0.6-0.6-1.5t0.6-1.5l6.5-6.6-6.5-6.5q-0.6-0.7-0.6-1.6t0.6-1.5l3-3q0.6-0.6 1.5-0.6t1.6 0.6l6.5 6.6 6.6-6.6q0.6-0.6 1.5-0.6t1.5 0.6l3.1 3q0.6 0.7 0.6 1.5t-0.6 1.6l-6.6 6.5 6.6 6.6q0.6 0.6 0.6 1.5z"></path>
        </g>
      </svg>
    </circle>
  </g>
</svg>;
```

[image]

I was able to display the circle, but I am having trouble displaying the svg x inside of it. Also, is there a way to optimize the viewBox values automatically without having to enter values, because I am having trouble getting the correct value to maximize the width and height of the icons.

```
<g transform="translate(36, 38)">
  <circle class="in-circle" r="110">
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 752 752">
      <path d="M196.56 543.17 472.2 384.03v-16.051l-275.64-159.14Zm284.89-334.59v332.99h74V208.58Z"></path>
    </svg>
  </circle>
</g>;
```

[image]

Also, I tried this, but again it doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: Can you make it more clear what you are trying to achieve? Some look-alike graphics would be nice

Comment: Just a circle with any svg icon right in the middle. Both needs to be in svg if possible.

Comment: Thought about merging two svg files, but the circle color needs to be changeable, while the white icon should stay fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't put the path inside the circle tag. You need to set the coordinates ofevery shape. In this case I would put the ctoss inside a symbol element with a viewBox and use it with `<use>`. This will allow me to give the use a position (x,y) and a width and a height.  In the nest example I'm giving the use a width and height of 100 vut you can choose another value:

```html
<svg  viewBox="-150 -150 300 300" > 
  <circle fill="blue" class="in-circle" r="110"></circle>
  <use href="#sym" width="100" height="100" x="-50" y="-50" />
  
  <symbol id="sym" viewBox="6.9 8 26.5 26.5" fill="red">
     <path id="kk" d="m33.5 29.5q0 0.9-0.7 1.5l-3 3.1q-0.6 0.6-1.5 0.6t-1.5-0.6l-6.6-6.6-6.5 6.6q-0.7 0.6-1.6 0.6t-1.5-0.6l-3-3.1q-0.6-0.6-0.6-1.5t0.6-1.5l6.5-6.6-6.5-6.5q-0.6-0.7-0.6-1.6t0.6-1.5l3-3q0.6-0.6 1.5-0.6t1.6 0.6l6.5 6.6 6.6-6.6q0.6-0.6 1.5-0.6t1.5 0.6l3.1 3q0.6 0.7 0.6 1.5t-0.6 1.6l-6.6 6.5 6.6 6.6q0.6 0.6 0.6 1.5z"></path>
  </symbol>
</svg>
```